# Using BibTeX file .bib in creating an authors index

Tags: bibtex, indexing

Is there any way to automatically create an authors index from a BibTeX `.bib` file? Not related to what is actually cited in the text? All I have found up till now was the `authorindex` package and this uses the `\cite` command which I do not use in my text (I only use `\bibentry`).

The way I've found is using `splitidx` in creating a separate index for the authors but then I would have to define in the text every single author per hand with `\sindex` which is nearly impossible..

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit. You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post: I've edited your post to remove this.

Comment: Can you precise your question? An index is a way to tell people where to find occurences of a name, concept etc. It has to be related to what is cited in the text! Perhaps what you are talking about is an Author list, which is different. Indices are tricky things. Removing the need to point to every occurences of a name is something important to point out, if this is the case.

Comment: `biblatex` offers automatic indexing of either cited names or titles. But since you're using `\bibentry` this wont help you. But swtiching to `biblatex` is a good idea anyway …

Comment: Martigan: I want to create summaries for more than 50 scientific papers. Each of the papers has up to 12 authors. I need at the end of the masterdocument a list of authors, referenced with all pages (to the respective summaries of their papers) - Example: Paper1 (author1,author2,author3) pages 1-12, Paper2 (author2, author4,author5) pages 13-16 - Desired output: author1 page1 // author2 page1,page 13 // author3 page1 // author4 page 13. I hope this is more clear :(

Comment: I cant' understand your question. Why do you have bib? Are the authors the authors of the article? How do you typeset this book?